Support multi-window mode on android devices - portrait
I want to start supporting multi-window mode, I began to test this on my Asus tablet and noticed that I have a very weird problem when the device is in portrait mode and my app is at the bottom of my screen it takes the XML layout file from 'layout' directory and not form 'layout-sw600dp', but when my app is at the top of the screen its act normal and take from the right directory.
The Asus device info :
Resolution: 800X1280 pixels.
Density: 160 dpi.
Physical Size: 10.03 inch.
I tested this also in two emulator devices and it happens also there.
Does somebody know why it is happening?





Just making sure you've seen: https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/main/MultiWindowPlayground

Thanks for your response. I've tried this in this project as well, and it happens there too.
